# VIM : Swap parts of strings in symmetrical blocks of code

Tags: regex, search, vim, replace, swap

So this problem must be as old as programming itself. If I have this block of code :

```
Arequest : A.state == IDLE & B.state == OUT     -> A.state == RUNNING
           A.state == IDLE & B.state == IN      -> A.state == POLLING
           A.state == IDLE & B.state == RUNNING -> A.state == WAITING
```

And the next block of code I want to type is this (A is swapped with B)

```
Brequest : B.state == IDLE & A.state == OUT     -> B.state == RUNNING
           B.state == IDLE & A.state == IN      -> B.state == POLLING
           B.state == IDLE & A.state == RUNNING -> B.state == WAITING
```

So basically any foo(A,B) into foo(B,A). How do I do that with VIM ? Been searching around a lot already, to no avail.
[Dr Chip's Swapstrings](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/#SWAPSTRINGS) will only swap occurrences of A and B that are between separators (dots, parentheses, spaces, ...) but Arequest (where the string to swap is part of a bigger string) won't be swapped into Brequest.
[Tim Pope's Abolish](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) won't do either (same reason).

Comment: if the task is just like your example, I would do `ctrl-v` and `r` instead of thinking about a (maybe lengthy) `:s` command

Comment: This kind of [copy-paste programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_and_paste_programming) is usually indicative of a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) - is there some reason why you can't factor common code like this into a function or macro or some such ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention Abolish I figured I would show you how that is done:

```
%S/{A,B}/{B,A}/wg
```

The secret is to use the `w` flag which means it only changes on words. The only missing part is to change `Arequest` to `Brequest` which can be done via `:Subvert` as well or by hand which ever is easier.

```
%S/{A,B,Arequest}/{B,A,Brequest}/wg
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a macro as you execute the changes once and move to next line and restart. Something like this:

```
qq/A<CR>cwB<ESC>/B<CR>cwA<ESC>/A<CR>cwB<ESC>^jq
```

run your macro with @q first time then repeat @@ until done

Comment: I'd do that with `f`, `qqrBfBrAfArB<CR>q2@q`.

Comment: The macro approach is a more general solution that can quite easily be adapted to slightly different data/problems...

Answer (score 1):

If your system has `tr` command, use that.

```
:%!tr AB BA
```

BTW, `A` in `WAITING` will be replaced.

Comment: That's when my question gets tricky ... Can I add exceptions to this ?

Comment: @Charles, `tr` translate character by character. No way to add exception using `tr`.

Comment: @Charles, See [this screencast](https://asciinema.org/a/7552) I just made. (used python script instead of `tr` to handle `WAITING`).  You can copy&paste script content in the screencast if you want.

Comment: However, I have zero understanding of the Python stuff you used - care to detail ?

Comment: @Charles, It find `\b[AB]` pattern. `\b` matches at word boundary. So the pattern will not match `WAITING`.

Comment: @Charles, [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) accepts callback function in addition to replacement string.

Comment: @Charles, Use the language you are familiar with. The point of the answer is using `:%!cmd`, you can give the buffer content to external program (stdin) and get back output of the program (stdout) to replace the content of the buffer.

Comment: This much I know. I wanted to actually get to understand the Python magic ou used, so thanks for that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47157/discussion-between-falsetru-and-charles)